# How to set correct Doctrine cascade relationship?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I have an old Page entity and a new Equivalent entity. My Page.orm.xml has now been edited to contain the following:

```
    <one-to-many target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent" field="equivalents">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-all/>
        </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
```

... and my PageAdmin class has been edited to include the following:

```
            ->add('equivalents', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => "Equivalents",
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'targetEntity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent',
            ))
```

... and my Equivalent entity definition includes the following:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $page;
```

So far so good. When I edit a page, I get a slick interface that allows me to add and edit new Equivalent records in an inline form. Very nice.

My problem comes when I try to save the Page entity. I get the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page#equivalents' that was not
>   configured to cascade persist operations for entity: some equivalent.
>   To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

**What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't my existing cascade definition cover this behavior? What can I do to fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions are missing the **associations fields**. Add **mapped-by** to:

```
<one-to-many target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent" field="equivalents" mapped-by="page">
    <cascade>
        <cascade-all/>
    </cascade>
</one-to-many>
```

and **inversedBy** to:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="equivalents", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $page;
```

### References

- [doctrine association updates owning side and inverse side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side)